# Neo4j Cypher Query Error while executing nested Foreach

Tags: foreach, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to execute the following cypher query to create a relationship between all the nodes which are present in the collection nodelist.

```
    START n=node(*)
    MATCH(n)
    WHERE has(n.Gender)
    WITH n.Gender as Gender
    WITH collect(n) as nodelist 
    FOREACH (i in RANGE(0,length(nodelist-2))|
    FOREACH(si in [nodelist[i]|
    FOREACH(si2 in[nodelist[i+1] |
    CREATE UNIQUE (si-[:KNOWS]->si2))))
```

It gives me an error in the second FOREACH loop at nodelist[i]  .

I tried putting nodelist(i) and it gives me an error saying 
              **`-' expected but '|' found**

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is your use-case for this? Kind of weird to connect all nodes just like this

Comment: my use case is to have a social graph where I want to have people with matching properties together .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a knows relation between all nodes in a collection:

```
 MATCH(n)
 WHERE has(n.Gender)
 WITH collect(n) as nodelist 
 FOREACH (x IN nodelist | 
     FOREACH (y IN filter(z IN  nodelist WHERE NOT (z=x)) | 
         MERGE (x)-[:knows]-(y)
     )
 )
```

Note the direction of your relations. Each node will be connected to each other node in nodelist once in a particular direction. If you want double relations i.e. a-[knows]->b as well as b-[:knows]->a you'll have to modify the query accordingly.

Comment: I am using neo4j community 1.9.6 .It gives an errror " ')' expected but 'M' found".Is the error because of the cypher version?

Comment: I used Create Unique command instead of merge and it worked.thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

Your first FOREACH should be like below. Also I think line 4 is redundant in your query. In case you want to collect gender you can directly do collect(n.Gender) as Gender. Incase you do need to use that line you need to pass `n` in the first `WITH` too, otherwise it wont be reconginized at the second `WITH` clause. Also you dont need to start with `START n=node(*)`

Try below

```
MATCH(n)
WHERE has(n.Gender)
WITH collect(n) as nodelist,collect(n.Gender) as Gender 
FOREACH (i in RANGE(0,length(nodelist)-2)|
FOREACH(si in [nodelist[i]]|
FOREACH(si2 in [nodelist[i+1]] |
CREATE UNIQUE (si)-[:KNOWS]->(si2) )))
```

Comment: Can you please explain why I do not need to start with start n=node(*)?